# Error when receiving null from database

Tags: c#, sql-server

When i execute this command on my database i receive sometimes result=null. i want to enter the "else" part when is this happening, but i receive

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. 
>   Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

```
DB database = new DB();
            int reservedSeats = 0;
            using (database.sqlConnection)
            {
                database.sqlConnection.Open();
                string command = "select SUM(nrLocuri) as result from Rezervari where idRand = @idRand and idShow=@idShow";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, database.sqlConnection))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@idRand", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idRand;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@idShow", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idShow;
                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (dr.Read())
                            if (dr["result"].ToString() != null)
                                reservedSeats = Convert.ToInt32(dr["result"].ToString());
                            else
                                return totalSeats;
                    }
                }
            }
            return totalSeats-reservedSeats;
```

Comment: You need to read up on exception handling.

Comment: what is the data type of the column result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if (dr["result"].ToString() != null)
```

Do:

```
if (dr["result"] != DbNull.Value)
```

When the `dr["result"]` returns a database `null`, its value is `DbNull.Value` - when you try to call `Convert.ToInt32` on this value, you get a format exception.

Comment: Does `DbNull` equate to `null`?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
if(!dr.IsDBNull(i)){   //replace i with the column id

  //get the data

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't rely on ordinals in your data access layer - column positions can change.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `SUM()` to return `0.00` in the event no records were found, replace it with:

```
COALESCE(SUM(...), 0.00)
```

COALESCE will return the first non-null value passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

try `isnull`:

```
string command = "select isnull(SUM(nrLocuri),0.00 )as result from Rezervari where idRand = @idRand and idShow=@idShow";
```